# Google Map places search box API refuses to load due to Content Security Policy

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

I am trying to use the Google Map places search box API, however I tried amending the Content Security Policy accordingly but ended up with the error as stated below.

HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://XXXX.projectsbit.org https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com 'unsafe-inline';  font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src 'self' https://www.google.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete  'unsafe-inline' ;media-src *">
```

Error message:

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains a source with an invalid path: '/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initautocomplete'. The query component, including the '?', will be ignored.

Comment: The sample from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) works for me on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/h9v465b0/) (and doesn't generate that error message).  Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits your issue.

Comment: i tried it on jsfiddle and i am aware that it works there. However, its the content policy that is preventing it from executing

Comment: This my original set of codes: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: http://XXXX.projectsbit.org https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com 'unsafe-inline';  font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

Comment: the error is coming from the Content Security Policy only

Comment: I am using the same sample source too

Comment: 1. Please edit your question to address comments. 2. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (in the question itself).